# Which version of angular-devkit/build-angular can I use?

Tags: angular, version, upgrade, angular12

I recently upgraded my Angular version from 11 to 12. When I run `npm install` I have 15 vulnerabilities and all of them want me to install `@angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.6` which to me seems to be the wrong version for angular 12. Are they compatible?

Comment: @angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.15"

Works for me, angular version is also the same.

Comment: they are not compatible. If you wish to install version 13, you need to upgrade your angular app further from 12 -> 13.

Comment: you may have one dependency that requires angular-devkit 13. have you checked all angular library's are on version 12?